# How can i read file fast?

Tags: python, list, data-structures

Why i have to wait(30seconds or more) when try to plot nearly 30mb data?
My data structure is right as a list? Or I should use which one?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x1=[]
y1=[]
with open("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\33mb.txt","r") as f4:
    for line in f4:
        data=line.split(",")
        if data[0] == "b'$GNGGA": 
            x1.append(float(data[1]))      #plot_x
            y1.append(float(data[1]))      #plot_y
            plt.plot(x1,y1)                #plot_()
            print("0")         
    print("finished")
    plt.show()                             #plot_show()
print("........................")
```

It reads the 33mb in less than one second(with print thousands "0" output) when remove the plot scripts.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You're adding to an array and plotting the entire array every time, effectively making this a quadratic operation. Move `plt.plot(x1,y1)` to immediately before `plt.show()`.

Comment: How come  didnt i think like that? Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x1=[]
y1=[]
with open("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\33mb.txt","r") as f4:
    for line in f4:
        data=line.split(",")
        if data[0] == "b'$GNGGA": 
            x1.append(float(data[1]))      #plot_x
            y1.append(float(data[1]))      #plot_y
            print("0")         
    print("finished")
    plt.plot(x1,y1)                #plot_()
    plt.show()                             #plot_show()
print("........................")
```

Should work as desired. [plt.plot()](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html) is able to draw entire table content at once. If you do that in the loop you are repeatedly drawing and redrawing after adding each new point, which is not the intention as far as I understand.